# Find where report email job is

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, report

I'm having a report (.rdl) in Visual Studio 2012. I know that this report is sent by email every day at 5AM, but I can't find the job that is doing this. I've been looking in SQL Server Agent jobs but it's not there.

I've heard the job can't be in SQL Server agent because then the pictures in the report can't be attached to the email (don't know if that's true?).

I have tried looking in Reporting Services Configuration Manager by connecting to the db, but I think it's only the service/server(?) properties there. Couldn't find any email job sending that report.

When I look at the dataset that is used for the report I can only find the source that fills it (a stored procedure), but that doesn't help me much..

Do you know where else to look to find this job? What is normal when trying to send a .rdl report email? Is it possible to do this from VS 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Report Subscriptions are run through SQL Server Agent.

You can get the job names, which are GUID type strings, with a query like this against your ReportServer database:

```
select JobName = rs.ScheduleID
  , ReportName = c.Name
from ReportSchedule rs
  inner join [Catalog] c on rs.ReportID = c.ItemID
```

Which will give a result like:

[image]

This matched jobs that can be seen in the SQL Server Agent:

[image]

You can check the job and see what it's doing:

[image]

i.e. calling a stored procedure on the ReportServer database.

See [SSRS Subscriptions and their SQL Server Agent job names](http://allen-mcguire.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/ssrs-subscriptions-and-their-sql-server.html) for a more detailed query.

Comment: I found the job. But is it possible to se some GUI for the configure rather than do this in the Job Properties ?

Comment: I find exactly what you have on the image, but the "exec...." in step 1 makes no sense to me, as you see @EventData is like a GUID as well

Comment: What are you looking for that you can't see when configuring the subscription through the Report Manager website?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157147.aspx i.e. the web interface to the Report Server. It will allow you to manage reports, folder, subscriptions, etc.